# How do I add spaces to the end of my string?

Tags: ruby, string, padding

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  HOw do I add an arbitrary amount of spaces to the end of my string?  I thought it was ljust but

```
2.4.0 :003 > line = "abcdef"
 => "abcdef"
2.4.0 :004 > line = line.ljust(4, " ")
 => "abcdef"
```

Notice my string is unchanged.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer to `ljust()` must be larger than the length of the string, or nothing will be appended. Since `line` is six chars, I believe you want:

```
line = "abcdef"
line = line.ljust(10, " ")
```

That'll add four spaces after the six characters already present in the string.

You could likely also do something along the lines of:

```
line = line.ljust(line.length + 4, " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a multiple of a spaces:

```
line = "abcdef"
line + ' '*5
 #=> "abcdef     "
line
 #=> "abcdef"
```

Or use `concat` which modifies the string.

```
line.concat(' '*5) 
 #=> "abcdef     "
line
 #=> "abcdef     "
```